# Classic ASP - Trying to search a string in another string variable. (Alternative to InStr function)

Tags: string, vbscript, asp-classic

In the following code `currentregion = 'BC'` and `Regions = 'ABC'`.

I am trying to find the `currentregion` in the `Regions` and normally it should hit `else` as the `if` condition is `false`.

But it returns `true` as `InStr` searches part of the string not string vs string. So BC being part of ABC it enters the if loop.

Is there a function in Classic ASP that I can compare a string to string but not part of the string like InStr function.

```
RegionSQL = "SELECT * FROM Regions Where Auth <= " & Session("U_Auth") & ";"                
Set rsRegion=Server.CreateObject("recordset")
rsRegion.Open RegionSQL,TheDB

If NOT rsRegion.EOF And NOT rsRegion.BOF Then
    rsRegion.MoveFirst
    While Not rsRegion.Eof 
        'Grab Current Region
        currentregion = rsRegion("RegionCodeShort")   

        If InStr(Regions,currentregion) > 0 Then
            checked = "checked"
        Else
            checked = ""
        End If
```

Comment: `if (Regions = currentregion) Then ...`

Comment: @DiskCrasher Yes, I can try that but in some cases there is a possibility that Regions can have multiple strings like Regions = "XYZ,NYR,ABC". In this case what can I do ?

Comment: [Split](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_split.asp) the string into an array first, then loop through and compare each element.

Comment: @DiskCrasher  You should post an answer with that.

Comment: @DiskCrasher Split function works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try [filtering the recordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540(v=bts.10).aspx) to the relevant region code, depending on what you're doing with the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Split](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_split.asp) the string into an array first, then loop through and compare each element

Comment: a = Split(Regions,",")

for each x in a
if x == currentRegion Then
checked = "checked"
else
checked = ""
next

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
If strcomp(Regions,currentregion,vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

instead of

```
If InStr(Regions,currentregion) > 0 Then
```

Comment: But `InStr` is useful when the string to be compared is very long

Comment: @GTAVLover: Eh?!

Comment: @GTAVLover: `StrComp` and `InStr` perform two different operations - `StrComp` compares the whole string byte by byte, breaking when it encounters the first incorrect byte (unicode or otherwise), whereas `InStr` returns the first position of the string within the other.  I would say the right tool for the job.  If you want to compare the whole string then use `StrComp`, whereas, if you want the location of one string in another, then use `InStr`. One good thing - both allow you to perform different types of text comparison. A straightforward compaison (`If a = b Then`) doesn't.

Comment: Okay, but isn't `InStr` useful in a situation that need to compare strings but one of the strings to be compared is very long?

Comment: Only if you want to look for **one string within the other**. If one string is *longer* than the other that means that they're not equal, so `StrComp` will inevitably fail. If I have a string `Apple Pear Banana` and I want to look for `Pear` then I can use `InStr`. `StrComp` will fail, however, if you want to compare the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Classic task for [Regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox (find("ABC", "(ABC)")) ' exist
    MsgBox (find("BC", "(ABC)")) ' not exist
End Sub

Function find(aString As String, ByVal pattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    Dim newArray() As String
    Dim cnt As Integer
    regEx.pattern = pattern
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(aString)
    Dim x As Integer
    x = matches.Count

    If x = 0 Then
        find = False
    Else
        find = True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: [Regular expressions are generally slower than string functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oanapl/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations/). Also, a nice clean way of achieving the final `If` result (`If x = 0 Then...`) is to simply say `find = x <> 0`.

Comment: there are cases that only regex can handle.

Comment: I have to admit that RegEx is a last resort for me - I only use it if I absolutely have to.