# Use a conditional "instr" function in Excel VBA to NOT add an item to a list

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, instr

I am trying to populate a list box with the open files.  The whole procedure will export the selected sheets from the existing file to another workbook and save it with a date time stamp appended into the same directory. It builds this export name and file from items in list boxes on a form.

The macro will be running from Personal.XLSB; the problem is that this becomes the active workbook and the exported file inherits the path and file name from it.  I want to build the export name by letting the use pick a file name from the list box BUT I don't want the Personal.XLSB to show in the list, further, once the user picks the file name (from the list of open files) I want to make that file the active file.   I have spent three hours with many variations INSTR (using numbers or just text) and even text comparison, OR USING "PERSONAL.xlsb" in the "instr" below, but I cant get it to work at all.   Ever have one of this days?????

Any insights anyone can give?

**CODE FOLLOWS:**

```
' Populate the open file name list box excluding Personal.xlsb

Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim wbopenText As String

ListBoxOpenFiles.Clear
    For Each wbOpen In Workbooks
    wbopenText = wbOpen.Name
    If InStr(1, wbopenText, "Per") = 0 Then
        ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name    ' add the name to the list
        MsgBox wbOpen.Name & "Added to list"
    End If
    
    If InStr(1, wbopenText, "Per") = 1 Then ' If "Personal" is NOT found skip
    
    End If                                  'Loop again
Next
' next step - make the existing file the active workbook

'still to do
```

Comment: [This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813925/how-to-get-the-path-of-current-worksheet-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

All of this should work (I am a big fan of intermediate variables, but I think the variable `wbopenText` is not needed in this case):

```
If StrComp("ABC", "personal.xlsb", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name 
End If

If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
   ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name
End If

If InStr(wb.Name, "PER") = 0 Then
    ' Dangerous as it would also skip "MySuperWorkbook"
    ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name
End If

If InStr(1, wb.Name, "per", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    ' Also dangerous as it would also skip "MySuperWorkbook"
    ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name
End If
```

Your second `If` is not needed (except you want to do something special with the Personal workbook).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216693/7599798 for some clarification.

To tell you how to get the selected item from the ListBox, you need to tell us where the listbox is located: On a sheet? On a Userform? Assuming you are able to get the selected name by your own and it is put into variable `SelectedWorkbook`

```
Dim wb As workbook
set wb = workbooks(SelectedWorkbook) 
wb.Activate
Debug.Print wb.FullName
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried many variations, including some that you had suggested, then penny dropeed. My file name was "PERSONAL.xlsb"  To get around this I used:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I tried many variations on this including the ones you had sent. Then the penny dropped, my file name was "PERSONAL.xlsb"   I changed the code to:

NEW CODE FOLLOWS

'Populate the open file name list box excluding Personal.xlsb
Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim wbopenUcase As String

```
ListBoxOpenFiles.Clear
    For Each wbOpen In Workbooks
    wbopenUcase = UCase(wbOpen.Name)                    ' convert name to uppercase just in case Personal XLSB has different cases
  
        If wbopenUcase <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
            ListBoxOpenFiles.AddItem wbOpen.Name            ' add the name to the list
        End If                                              'Loop again
    Next
```