# Excluding commented declarations in an .h file using Excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA, I'm having a problem with an excel macro with function

```
` StrComp(FileLine, "*/")`
```

The purpose of the code is to find duplicates in an .h file.

And I want to exclude all commented declarations, so I've added this piece of code:

```
VarIsAComment = StrComp(FileLine, "//#define", vbTextCompare)
```

and it's working fine, but the problem starts when I try to find comment with "/*"..
I've tryied this code:

```
While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, FileLine
            CurLineNum = CurLineNum + 1
            If (StrComp(FileLine, "#define", vbBinaryCompare)) Then
            
                VarIsAComment = StrComp(FileLine, "//#define", vbTextCompare) //Woks fine
                If (StrComp(FileLine, "/*")) Then CommentStarted = 1 //not working
                If (StrComp(FileLine, "*/")) Then CommentStarted = 0
```

So the problem is that if FileLine is something like this:

```
#define mBlk    bytem[12]/*comment*/
```

it works fine, but when FileLine is only /* CommentStarted stays to false and then goes to true only on the next line and then returns to false in the same cycle.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you researched how `StrComp` works? It will return a zero (`0`) when the two strings match, not a `True`. Also, asterisks (`*`) are treated as wildcards.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood `StrComp`. It will check if two strings are *identical*. If yes, it returns 0, else it returns either -1 or +1 (depending on which string is "smaller"). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215786/best-way-to-compare-strings-in-vba/45216693#45216693. You are probably looking for `InStr`

Answer (score 1):

As written in the comments, you seem to misunderstand how `StrComp` works. Your statement `StrComp(FileLine, "#define", vbBinaryCompare` will always return either 1 or -1, except if the line is *exactly* `"#define"`. Both values 1 and -1 are interpreted as `True` (in VBA, as in most languages, 0 is converted to `False` and every other value is converted to `True`).

Similarly, `VarIsAComment = StrComp(FileLine, "//#define", vbTextCompare)` will always be True except if the line is *exactly* `"//#define"`.

What you want is to check

**o** If line *starts* with `#define`:

```
If FileLine like "#define*" Then
```

**o** If line contains `#define`:

```
If InStr(FileLine, "#define") > 0 Then
```

**o** Get rid of the // comment:

```
Dim p  As Long
p = InStr(FileLine, "//")
If p > 0 Then 
   If p > 1 Then FileLine = Left(FileLine, p-1) Else FileLine = ""
End If
```

**o** Get rid of /* comments and check if we start (or end) a comment block

```
Dim p1 As Long, p2  As Long
p1 = InStr(FileLine, "/*")
p2 = InStr(FileLine, "*/")
If p1 > 0 Then 
    If p1 > 1 Then FileLine = Left(FileLine, p1-1) Else FileLine = ""
    CommentStarted = True
End If
If p2 > p1 Then CommentStarted = False
```