# InStr value check, how do I ignore quotations marks?

Tags: excel, vba

If I do have certain values represented by text on my excel table and I want to check it and depend on outcome proceed with actions, but some similar data contain different signs in it, is there a way to ignore those signs?

For example

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| a | “A” |

I want to proceed only in case if cell contain value A regardless if A is in between quotations marks, capital or raw.

I do have simple code but cannot figure out how to ignore quotations marks or case sensitivity… I do understand that the problem is primitive but couldn’t find or figure out the solution

Appreciate your help in advance.

```
If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "A") > 0 Then
```

I do understand that I can use OR function and add all possible variable in a line, but is there more elegant solution rather than this?

```
If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "A") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cell.Value, Chr(34) & "A" & Chr(34)) > 0  Then
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the respective cell **contains** A (no case sensitive) or **the whole value** is A or "A" (no case sensitive)? For the second scenario which looks more probable, try `if cell.value = "A" or cell value = """" & "A" & """" Then`.

Comment: I want to know that cell contain A. I do not care at all either A is capital, lowercase (a), in between quotation marks (“A”). I just want to proceed then in case cell contain a.

Comment: So, you do not need to check for **ONLY** A. And you know that `instr(Cell.Value, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0` will be `> 0` for "and", "call" strings, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Instr()` looks for the value you give up, however, it is case sensitive so you'll have to use
`UCase()`:

`If InStr(1, UCase(Cell.Value), "A") > 0 Then`

But do try to use more distinctive variable names, you'll end up with issues sooner or later with pre-set variables of VBE.

**Edit**:
Better to use the built-in `vbTextCompare` as FunThomas mentioned.
`If InStr(1, Cell.Value, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

Over a smaller array/text value it won't matter much but I tested with a repeating a "A" "a" over 180k rows and 6 columns and did notice a difference. "Text comparison" = "ignores case-sensitivity", should've known.

Comment: Better to use `InStr(1, Cell.Value, "A", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` - this will make it case insensitive. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45216693/7599798

Comment: @FunThomas and notus_panda thank you guys, all works just fine.

Comment: Aha, was about to reply that it might not matter much and it may use `UCase` in code behind but after increasing the range a bit more, I did see a 1s shave off the time it took with the `vbTextCompare` over `UCase`. Thanks @FunThomas

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple VBA function that does what you need.

```
Public Function fnIn(sToSearch As String, sToFind As String) As Boolean
 If IsNull(sToFind) Then fnIn = False
 If InStr(1, sToSearch, sToFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
     fnIn = True
 Else
     fnIn = False
 End If
End Function
```

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: thank you, this is way too advance for my current level and tasks but I will look into it.

Comment: @VladislavZinovyev sorry I should have included a test routine. `Sub sbTest()  MsgBox fnIn("Hello", "h")  End Sub`